# SmppInboundChannelAdapter AbstractReceivingMessageListener

Tags: spring-integration, smpp

In the `SmppInboundChannelAdapter` the declaration of the `AbstractReceivingMessageListener` has a no-op for the `onDeliveryReceipt` method.
I however am setting the `registered_delivery` token in the outbound smpp gateway and would like to receive the delivery receipt.  If I add an implementation of `MessageReceiverListener` to the set of listeners in the outbound gateway will that get the delivery receipt or will the inbound adapter get it first?

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking to `SmppInboundChannelAdapter` and `SmppOutboundGateway` we see that they uses the same `ExtendedSmppSession` instance (if you do that from the config, of course).

Now let's take a look to the `DelegatingMessageReceiverListener` used from the `ExtendedSmppSessionAdaptingDelegate`. It just iterates and invokes all the configured listeners:

```
public void onAcceptDeliverSm(DeliverSm deliverSm) throws ProcessRequestException {
    for (MessageReceiverListener l : this.messageReceiverListenerSet)
        l.onAcceptDeliverSm(deliverSm);
}
```

And from here it does not have a value that an internal `SmppInboundChannelAdapter` `AbstractReceivingMessageListener` implementation does nothing in its `onDeliveryReceipt`, because your custom `listener` on the `session` can handle that.